# Scale MKAnnotationView with Map Zoom

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I want to scale an MKAnnotationView as the map zooms in and out so that if my view takes up 100 meters, it'll continue to visually take up that much.

Here's what I have so far:

```
- (void)detectPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinch{
    NSArray* annotations = self.mapView.annotations;
    for(id<MKAnnotation>annotation in annotations){
        if(![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] && [annotation isMemberOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]]){
            CustomAnnotationView* annotationView = (CustomAnnotationView*)[self.mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
            CGAffineTransform transform;
            MKZoomScale currentZoomScale = self.mapView.bounds.size.width / self.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width;
            self.previousMapScale = (self.previousMapScale == 0 ? currentZoomScale : self.previousMapScale);
            if(self.previousMapScale == currentZoomScale) return;
            else transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(pinch.scale*((currentZoomScale-self.previousMapScale)+1), pinch.scale*((currentZoomScale-self.previousMapScale)+1));
            annotationView.transform = transform;
            self.previousMapScale = (pinch.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ? 0 : currentZoomScale);
        }
    }
}
```

This almost works except for every pinch after the first one, the annotation view doesn't keep it's previous state and gets scaled weirdly. After the first call to the pinch gesture recognizer handler, it scales correctly for the rest of the gesture. It's just that initial part of the pinch.

Anybody know where I'm going wrong with my math?

Comment: just my 2 cents: even though shadow likely doesn't agree I don't think this is a good approach in general. While it may be good in his case, in general Overlays are scaled, annotations are not. Same pattern in GoogleMaps BTW

Comment: I agree except that in this use case, I have to reduce the amount of scaling by a particular ratio (as my designer's requested) so it made more sense to use MKAnnotationView although I may switch in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, it wasn't in the math, it was because I was doing `transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);` instead of passing in the existing transform using `CGAffineTransformScale`. I can't take credit for the math, I found it on an SO post, if I find the post, I'll add the credits at the bottom.

The below code is the complete code for scaling annotations with a map view.

```
- (void)detectPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinch{
    NSArray* annotations = self.mapView.annotations;
    for(id<MKAnnotation>annotation in annotations){
        if(![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]] && [annotation isMemberOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]]){
            CustomAnnotationView* annotationView = (CustomAnnotationView*)[self.mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
            CGAffineTransform transform;
            CGFloat currentScale = self.view.width/self.view.bounds.size.width;
            CGFloat newScale = pinch.scale*currentScale;
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(annotationView.transform, newScale, newScale);
           annotationView.transform = transform;
           pinch.scale = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I figured out a slightly better way to scale the annotation view.
Instead of using the scale property on the pinch gesture which sometimes would lead to the view being scaled wrong if the pinch was sharp and quick, simply do this:

```
CLLocationDistance currentMapWidth = [self.mapView mapWidthInMeters];
CGFloat scale = self.previousMapWidth/currentMapWidth;
//apply the transformation with that scale
self.previousMapWidth = currentMapWidth;
```

`mapWidthInMeters` is a category on MKMapView.

```
- (CLLocationDistance)mapWidthInMeters{
    CLLocationDegrees deltaLongitude = self.region.span.longitudeDelta;
    CGFloat latitudeCircumference = 40075160 * cos(self.region.center.latitude * M_PI / 180);
    return deltaLongitude * latitudeCircumference/360;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

thats what MKOverlays are for. They are naturally scaled

Comment: Been down that road, MKOverlayRenderer is WAY too cpu intensive and heavy. I'm downvoting this answer because it's not answering the question which was, "How to scale an MKAnnotationView" not "How to do it differently"

Comment: on SO you learn to disregard the question title and rather see what the OP wants to do ;)

Comment: also I'm also not sure about your statement that overlays are too cpu intensive ;) but hey -- whatever you claim :)